# How to Install a war to AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I have a `Java RESTful Services` talking to `MySQL` that has been running perfectly on a `Wildfly Server` and `OpenShift` Servers. I now need to deploy it to `Amazon Web Services`.

Using Eclipse Neo2, I do a `Maven install`:

[image]

It generates the following war file:

[image]

I go to `AWS Elastic Beanstalk` to create a web app:

[image]

I **upload** the `war` that Maven generated above:

[image]

Then `Create App`....

After a few minutes....

[image]

If I click on the URL, I get:

> `502 Bad Gateway`

I go to the logs, but there is nothing really here. No errors, but I cannot seem to find any Maven Build.

From the Eclipse AWS Plugin:

[image]

Any help on how to install a Java project to AWS will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

```
Here are the last 100 lines of the logs:

-------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
-------------------------------------
2017/02/21 13:28:15 [error] 2134#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 41.144.3.125, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "lowcost-env.jz2iwdhkjz.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2017/02/21 13:28:15 [error] 2134#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 41.144.3.125, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico", host: "lowcost-env.jz2iwdhkjz.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://lowcost-env.jz2iwdhkjz.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"



-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-activity.log
-------------------------------------
  Executing: HOME=/tmp /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/ruby /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/foreman export supervisord --procfile /var/app/staging/Procfile --root /var/app/current --app application --log /var/log/ --user webapp --template /opt/elasticbeanstalk/private/config/foreman/supervisord --env /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/elasticbeanstalk.env /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/supervisor
  [foreman export] writing: application.conf
  Executing: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/log-conf -n supervisor -l'/var/log/supervisord.log' -t bundlelogs

  Executing: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/log-conf -n containerlistener -l'/var/log/eb-container-listener.log' -t bundlelogs

[2017-02-21T13:25:33.299Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/01_configure_xray.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:33.519Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/01_configure_xray.sh] : Completed activity.
[2017-02-21T13:25:33.520Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03_configure_proxy.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:33.890Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03_configure_proxy.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Executing: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/log-conf -n nginx -l'/var/log/nginx/*'

  Executing: /usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/nginx/nginx.conf
  nginx: the configuration file /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
  nginx: configuration file /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
[2017-02-21T13:25:33.890Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre.
[2017-02-21T13:25:33.891Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:34.361Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:34.361Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Completed activity.
[2017-02-21T13:25:34.394Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Completed activity.
[2017-02-21T13:25:34.394Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage0/InfraCleanEbExtension] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:34.397Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage0/InfraCleanEbExtension] : Completed activity. Result:
  Cleaned ebextensions subdirectories from /var/app/staging.
[2017-02-21T13:25:34.397Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage0] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup stage 0 completed
[2017-02-21T13:25:34.398Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:34.398Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:34.399Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/01_stop_before_promote.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:35.003Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/01_stop_before_promote.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Executing: /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf stop application:*
  unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock no such file
  Executing: /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf stop all
  unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock no such file
  Executing: /sbin/status supervisord
  supervisord stop/waiting
[2017-02-21T13:25:35.003Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/01stop_xray.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:37.254Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/01stop_xray.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Executing: if ( initctl status xray | grep start ); then initctl stop xray; fi
  xray start/running, process 1266
  xray stop/waiting
[2017-02-21T13:25:37.254Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/02start_xray.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:37.472Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/02start_xray.sh] : Completed activity.
[2017-02-21T13:25:37.473Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/03_stop_proxy.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:37.913Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/03_stop_proxy.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Executing: service nginx stop

[2017-02-21T13:25:37.914Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/05_promote_application.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:38.121Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/05_promote_application.sh] : Completed activity.
[2017-02-21T13:25:38.121Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/07_start_application.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:38.377Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/07_start_application.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Executing: /sbin/start supervisord
  supervisord start/running, process 2085
[2017-02-21T13:25:38.378Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/09_start_proxy.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:41.418Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/09_start_proxy.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Executing: service nginx stop

  Executing: service nginx start
  Starting nginx: [  OK  ]
  Executing: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-track-pidfile --proxy nginx

  Executing: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-configure --appstat-log-path /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log --appstat-unit sec --appstat-timestamp-on 'completion'

  Executing: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-restart

[2017-02-21T13:25:41.419Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/11_stop_after_promote.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.198Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/11_stop_after_promote.sh] : Completed activity.
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.198Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact.
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.198Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.199Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post.
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.199Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/PostInitHook] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.199Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1/PostInitHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/postinit.
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.200Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/StartupStage1] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup stage 1 completed
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.200Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.200Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.200Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation/10-config.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.538Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation/10-config.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Disabled forced hourly log rotation.
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.539Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/addons/logpublish/hooks/config.
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.539Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigCWLAgent] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.540Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigCWLAgent/10-config.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.990Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigCWLAgent/10-config.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Log streaming option setting is not specified, ignore cloudwatch logs setup.

  Disabled log streaming.
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.990Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigCWLAgent] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/addons/logstreaming/hooks/config.
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.990Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1/AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.990Z] INFO  [1958]  - [Application deployment thewhozoo-source@1] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup succeeded
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.457Z] INFO  [2652]  - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.457Z] INFO  [2652]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.457Z] INFO  [2652]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.457Z] INFO  [2652]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.458Z] INFO  [2652]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...



-------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/access.log
-------------------------------------
41.144.3.125 - - [21/Feb/2017:13:28:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36" "-"
41.144.3.125 - - [21/Feb/2017:13:28:15 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "http://lowcost-env.jz2iwdhkjz.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36" "-"



-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
-------------------------------------
[2017-02-21T13:24:47.399Z] INFO  [1772]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish", "logstreaming"].
[2017-02-21T13:24:47.403Z] INFO  [1772]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2017-02-21T13:24:47.403Z] INFO  [1772]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-02-21T13:24:47.403Z] DEBUG [1772]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::CloudFormation::Init||Infra-WriteApplication2||files..
[2017-02-21T13:24:47.406Z] DEBUG [1772]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||ManifestFileS3Key..
[2017-02-21T13:24:47.703Z] INFO  [1772]  : Finding latest manifest from bucket 'elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-878916547556' with prefix 'resources/environments/e-mxkaa42emx/_runtime/versions/manifest_'.
[2017-02-21T13:24:47.994Z] INFO  [1772]  : Found manifest with key 'resources/environments/e-mxkaa42emx/_runtime/versions/manifest_1487683380852'.
[2017-02-21T13:24:48.015Z] INFO  [1772]  : Updated manifest cache: deployment ID 1 and serial 1.
[2017-02-21T13:24:48.015Z] DEBUG [1772]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-PreInit.
[2017-02-21T13:24:48.016Z] INFO  [1772]  : Executing Initialization
[2017-02-21T13:24:48.017Z] INFO  [1772]  : Executing command: CMD-PreInit...
[2017-02-21T13:24:48.017Z] INFO  [1772]  : Executing command CMD-PreInit activities...
[2017-02-21T13:24:48.017Z] DEBUG [1772]  : Setting environment variables..
[2017-02-21T13:24:48.017Z] INFO  [1772]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-PreInit...
[2017-02-21T13:24:48.017Z] DEBUG [1772]  : Running stages of Command CMD-PreInit from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2017-02-21T13:24:48.017Z] INFO  [1772]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-PreInit...
[2017-02-21T13:24:48.017Z] DEBUG [1772]  : Loaded 3 actions for stage 0.
[2017-02-21T13:24:48.017Z] INFO  [1772]  : Running 1 of 3 actions: InfraWriteConfig...
[2017-02-21T13:24:48.022Z] INFO  [1772]  : Running 2 of 3 actions: DownloadSourceBundle...
[2017-02-21T13:24:50.400Z] INFO  [1772]  : Running 3 of 3 actions: PreInitHook...
[2017-02-21T13:24:51.261Z] INFO  [1772]  : Running AddonsAfter for command CMD-PreInit...
[2017-02-21T13:24:55.787Z] INFO  [1772]  : Command CMD-PreInit succeeded!
[2017-02-21T13:24:55.787Z] INFO  [1772]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[]}]}
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.554Z] DEBUG [1958]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.555Z] DEBUG [1958]  : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.558Z] DEBUG [1958]  : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-08ac79d878b69d8c9)..
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.558Z] INFO  [1958]  : Command is applicable to this instance (i-08ac79d878b69d8c9)..
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.558Z] DEBUG [1958]  : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.558Z] INFO  [1958]  : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.559Z] INFO  [1958]  : Received command CMD-Startup: {"execution_data":"{\"leader_election\":\"true\"}","instance_ids":["i-08ac79d878b69d8c9"],"command_name":"CMD-Startup","api_version":"1.0","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","request_id":"d7d5aa7e-f838-11e6-bd49-cb483cb60a04","command_timeout":"600"}
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.559Z] INFO  [1958]  : Command processor should execute command.
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.559Z] DEBUG [1958]  : Storing current stage..
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.559Z] DEBUG [1958]  : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.559Z] DEBUG [1958]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.559Z] DEBUG [1958]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.560Z] DEBUG [1958]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.561Z] INFO  [1958]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish", "logstreaming"].
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.563Z] INFO  [1958]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.563Z] INFO  [1958]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.563Z] DEBUG [1958]  : Refreshing metadata...
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.997Z] DEBUG [1958]  : Refreshed environment metadata.
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.997Z] DEBUG [1958]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2017-02-21T13:25:28.998Z] DEBUG [1958]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2017-02-21T13:25:29.000Z] INFO  [1958]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish", "logstreaming"].
[2017-02-21T13:25:29.002Z] INFO  [1958]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2017-02-21T13:25:29.002Z] INFO  [1958]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-02-21T13:25:29.002Z] DEBUG [1958]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-Startup.
[2017-02-21T13:25:29.004Z] INFO  [1958]  : Executing Application deployment
[2017-02-21T13:25:29.005Z] INFO  [1958]  : Executing command: CMD-Startup...
[2017-02-21T13:25:29.005Z] INFO  [1958]  : Executing command CMD-Startup activities...
[2017-02-21T13:25:29.005Z] DEBUG [1958]  : Setting environment variables..
[2017-02-21T13:25:29.005Z] INFO  [1958]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-Startup...
[2017-02-21T13:25:29.005Z] DEBUG [1958]  : Running stages of Command CMD-Startup from stage 0 to stage 1...
[2017-02-21T13:25:29.005Z] INFO  [1958]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-Startup...
[2017-02-21T13:25:29.005Z] INFO  [1958]  : Running leader election...
[2017-02-21T13:25:29.424Z] INFO  [1958]  : Instance is Leader.
[2017-02-21T13:25:29.425Z] DEBUG [1958]  : Loaded 7 actions for stage 0.
[2017-02-21T13:25:29.425Z] INFO  [1958]  : Running 1 of 7 actions: HealthdLogRotation...
[2017-02-21T13:25:29.437Z] INFO  [1958]  : Running 2 of 7 actions: HealthdHTTPDLogging...
[2017-02-21T13:25:29.438Z] INFO  [1958]  : Running 3 of 7 actions: HealthdNginxLogging...
[2017-02-21T13:25:29.438Z] INFO  [1958]  : Running 4 of 7 actions: EbExtensionPreBuild...
[2017-02-21T13:25:29.990Z] INFO  [1958]  : Running 5 of 7 actions: AppDeployPreHook...
[2017-02-21T13:25:33.891Z] INFO  [1958]  : Running 6 of 7 actions: EbExtensionPostBuild...
[2017-02-21T13:25:34.394Z] INFO  [1958]  : Running 7 of 7 actions: InfraCleanEbExtension...
[2017-02-21T13:25:34.397Z] INFO  [1958]  : Running stage 1 of command CMD-Startup...
[2017-02-21T13:25:34.398Z] DEBUG [1958]  : Loaded 3 actions for stage 1.
[2017-02-21T13:25:34.398Z] INFO  [1958]  : Running 1 of 3 actions: AppDeployEnactHook...
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.198Z] INFO  [1958]  : Running 2 of 3 actions: AppDeployPostHook...
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.199Z] INFO  [1958]  : Running 3 of 3 actions: PostInitHook...
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.200Z] INFO  [1958]  : Running AddonsAfter for command CMD-Startup...
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.990Z] INFO  [1958]  : Command CMD-Startup succeeded!
[2017-02-21T13:25:42.991Z] INFO  [1958]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[]}]}
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.447Z] DEBUG [2652]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.447Z] DEBUG [2652]  : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.451Z] DEBUG [2652]  : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-08ac79d878b69d8c9)..
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.451Z] INFO  [2652]  : Command is applicable to this instance (i-08ac79d878b69d8c9)..
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.451Z] DEBUG [2652]  : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.451Z] INFO  [2652]  : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.451Z] INFO  [2652]  : Received command CMD-TailLogs: {"execution_data":"{\"aws_access_key_id\":\"ASIAJH5NV2SOYPG4UTPQ\",\"signature\":\"cFoo1WL7sJc\\\/9FT82Rwx+0Qw1is=\",\"security_token\":\"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\",\"policy\":\"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\"}","instance_ids":["i-08ac79d878b69d8c9"],"data":"19e13fdf-f83b-11e6-ba29-1197628be468","command_name":"CMD-TailLogs","api_version":"1.0","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","request_id":"19e13fdf-f83b-11e6-ba29-1197628be468","command_timeout":"600"}
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.451Z] INFO  [2652]  : Command processor should execute command.
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.451Z] DEBUG [2652]  : Storing current stage..
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.451Z] DEBUG [2652]  : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.451Z] DEBUG [2652]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.451Z] DEBUG [2652]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.452Z] DEBUG [2652]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.453Z] INFO  [2652]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish", "logstreaming"].
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.456Z] INFO  [2652]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.456Z] INFO  [2652]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.456Z] DEBUG [2652]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.456Z] INFO  [2652]  : Executing CMD-TailLogs
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.457Z] INFO  [2652]  : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.457Z] INFO  [2652]  : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.457Z] DEBUG [2652]  : Setting environment variables..
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.457Z] INFO  [2652]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.457Z] DEBUG [2652]  : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.457Z] INFO  [2652]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.458Z] DEBUG [2652]  : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
[2017-02-21T13:39:03.458Z] INFO  [2652]  : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
```

Comment: Is there any data base stuff integrated in ur POC ?

Comment: I do have a MySQL database, but on AWS I have not installed it yet. I did try install it earlier (Amazon RDS), but got the same error.

Comment: I think, You need to install a MySQL Aurora in RDS and need to enable it for the application to use it.

Comment: Thanks, I am busy creating the MySQL now. A quick question, how does AWS work, because locally and on OpenShift, I would install a WildFly server. Does AWS have its own server?  Is that what AWS Elastic Beanstalk effectively is?

Answer (score 1):

Got it working.  It needed to be set up as:

```
Platform:  Tomcat
```

and not:

```
Platform:  Java
```